# What does the "@" sign for complex number mean in R5RS

Tags: floating-point, scheme, r5rs

When parsing numbers, I find the following rule in R5RS (7.1.1)

```
<complex R> -> <real R> @ <real R>
```

I've searched the entire document but this usage of `@` cannot be found anywhere.

I guess `x@y` is equal to `(make-polar x y)`(found in 6.2.5) but still feel uncomfortable
since no definition for it is found in the report.

Can someone point me to related documents that can confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R7RS, section 6.2.5 (Syntax of numerical constants):

> There are two notations provided for non-real complex numbers: the *rectangular notation* *a*`+`*b*`i`, where *a* is the real part and *b* is the imaginary part; and the *polar notation* *r*`@`*θ*, where *r* is the magnitude and *θ* is the phase (angle) in radians. These are related by the equation *a* + *b* i = *r* cos *θ* + (*r* sin *θ*)i. All of *a*, *b*, *r*, and *θ* are real numbers.

I can't find the equivalent text in R5RS, though. :-(